# What song is played when Ace is questioning why everyone came to save him in episode 468?

Tags: one-piece, music

In *One Piece* episode 468 around 6:38, there's a song when Ace is questioning why everyone came to save him. The song sounds like a Gregorian chant.

I tried going through the soundtracks but I couldn't find it.

What is that song?

Comment: The actual song probably started from 5:58 with strings orchestration and ended at 6:55.

Answer (score -2):

Medwyn Goodall - Inside the Dragons Lair - 
A Wooden Door Opens onto the Balcony That Overlooks the Monks at Service.

Comment: I don't think that's the correct song. The melody in the beginning of the chant is different.

Answer (score -3):

Go to this link to see the name of the song!
http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/One_Piece_Music

Comment: While the content of the link may answer the question if the wikia was to change or the site goes down this answer would be invalid. please quote the relevant parts from the page which answers the question